# Share Apple Store bag

Tags: apple-store

I've got 4 purchases in my [Apple Store bag](https://www.apple.com/shop/bag) and I would like to share the whole bag to someone (with the all the options for each item carefully set already).

I want to achieve this without needing to take screenshot/capturing pdf or to give my login credentials to the person I want to share the bag with.

In the link to my bag, there's no characteristics that are significant, it's the same bag link for everyone (https://www.apple.com/shop/bag).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because **customer support** questions about Apple’s e-commerce site should be directed to Apple as only they can adequately  address any issues.

Comment: @Allan See https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4224/489896

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried both on the website and in the Apple Store app, there doesn't seem to be a way to share shopping bag. What you can do is to save all selected products for later, and share a link to the list you get with somebody else.

This allows other to select the product you've configured and ordering it in exactly that configuration.

Comment: Okay, thanks, it works!